# Counting combinations in Java?

Tags: java

I am aiming to build a program with counting combinations so it counts all products from 1 to 10 like this: (1x1, 1x2, ..., 1x10, 2x1, 2x2, ...., 2x10, 3x10, ...., 10x1, 10x2, ...., 10x10)

Repeats allowed.

I started but I cannot do this properly.

I have

```
public static void main(String [] args){

int x = 1; int y=1;

while(y<=10){
 System.out.println(x*y);
} //while loop closure

   } //public static void closure.
```

The problem is this only works for x=1, but doesnt go on. What can I do here?

Thank you!

Comment: first you should change `xy` to `x * y`..

Comment: you also need to initialized y to 1

Comment: Fixed, I typed this by hand so I had some typos. This part was working perfectly, I just cant get x to increase.

Comment: @Aakarsh every programmer type by hand :p , you need to increment x as `++x`

Comment: Your comments such as `//public static void closure.` are typically used when the opening brace is so far away from the closing brace that the reader may have difficulty finding it. There's no need for such a comment for small methods. Also, don't use the word 'closure' in this context, because it means something else in computer science. The fact that you have a closing brace is enough to indicate what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- You don't initialize the variable y, so your program won't compile.
- You never increment y, so you have an infinite loop
- You don't increment x either.
- Putting two variables next to each other won't make them multiply. You'll get a "cannot resolve symbol" error.

I would highly recommend you go through some [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) so that you understand what you are doing. Here is the corrected code:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    for(int y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
        System.out.println(x * y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code need a little change

- first Initialized variable `y`
- you need 2 loop for that operation to happened
- You also need to increment variable `x`

  ```
   public static void main(String [] args){
    int x = 1; int y=1;

   while(x<=10){
     while(y<=10){
        System.out.println(x+"X"+y+" ");
        ++y;
     }
   ++x;
   } //while loop closure
  } //public static void closure.
  ```

It will print as expected in your program.